# QGIS Grid Union Issues

Tags: qgis, density, union, grids-graticules, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map of ice concentration over Lake Erie. I have data for all the lakes (I can clip it all at the end), which are in a point shapefile. I have laid a grid over the area and I am able to create a union between the two, but the attribute table pulls up NULL for each of the ice data attributes added to the new grid table. Data can be found at: http://www.glerl.noaa.gov/data/pgs/glice/glice.html (I used 20080211) I am just not sure how to assign a value to each grid cell with the given data type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the point information to the polygon grid, you can use the tool "Join Attributes by Location" (Vector > Data Management Tools).